# Refreshing canvas erases previous data

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm making something like Battleships game on Canvas.
Let's see the field:
[image]

The problem is: when I press another cell, the yellow one will become black again. And I want to save it's state, so that this yellow cell won't become black again.

Here's the code what to do when hit:

```
// it's some method A
case 1:
        drawHit = true;
        this.draw_x = x;
        this.draw_y = y;
        invalidate();
        break;
```

and

```
// It's in onDraw() method
if (drawHit == true) {
        Log.d(TAG, "drawHit! drawX = " + draw_x + ", drawY = " + draw_y);
        Paint ship = new Paint();
        ship.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ship_color));
        Rect r = new Rect(draw_x*rebro_piece, draw_y * rebro_piece, (draw_x+1) * rebro_piece, (draw_y+1)*rebro_piece);
        canvas.drawRect(r, ship);
        drawHit = false; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this problem in a recent application printing Points on a Canvas. Each point got different colour and size and I had to save their state.

All you have to do is create a small class in which you save your cell, saving your information and store all of them in a List. In the onDraw() method, before the drawRect(), update your Paint object with the color you already saved.

I'll show you here my snippet. (1 suggestion: do not instantiate the Paint every time you call onDraw, it's better to declare it outside, maybe as a private variable in your class)

```
private class MyPoint {

        private float x;
        private float y;
        private int color;
        private int size;
    // + constructor, getters and setters
}

@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (MyPoint point : points) {
            paint.setColor(point.get_color());
            canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, current_size, paint);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite a noob at Android coding, could you please explain, what will that class do? Redraw the entire field just before drawing a new cell?

Comment: Every time you call invalidate() you are forcing your App to call the onDraw() method asking something like "oh dear Canvas, something has changed.. could you please redraw yourself? Thanks!". Now, if you have to show (like in my case) an array/list of points (different colour, different size) you must code it in your onDraw() method. What I did was "Dear View, every time you use the onDraw() methods please scan every point in my points list and draw a circle around its coordinates BUT, before that, set the colour used by the painter to the one saved in Point class.

Comment: And what to do if I have yellow rectangulars and white dots (dots and rects are of different size) ? Can I store them in one list? Or make two lists?

Comment: You can put a private int shape; and set it to 0 if blank, 1 if yellow rect or 2 if white dot. Or every single future shape you have not thought to yet :)

Comment: tell us if you are good enough with this way (and don't forget to accept the answer you liked the most ;)  )

Answer (score 1):

I Believe the best solution is to change your approach, here's one simple example:

Create a class to model the action, like:

```
public class BattleTurn {
 //here you save your Rect you had on your onDraw()
 //but you will have to create the moment user clicks
 private Rect rect;
 private boolean hit;
 //...
}
```

Keep a List for each turn of the game.

```
List<BattleTurn> turns = new ArrayList<BattleTurn>();
```

Every time someone play you add a new turn (`turns.add(...)`) and invalidate your canvas so it will redraw itself.

On your `onDraw()`, you go through each turn and draw it:

```
//for each turn you draw it on the canvas
for (BattleTurn turn: turns){
 //draw the turn like you already do
 if (turn.getHit()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "drawHit! drawX = " + draw_x + ", drawY = " + draw_y);
        Paint ship = new Paint();
        ship.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ship_color));
        canvas.drawRect(turn.getRect(), ship);
 }
}
```

Comment: Well, there're 100 cells and they'll be touched randomly. Isn't it very "heavy" to redraw every time? And will it keep the original position?

Comment: On most devices that will have a very good performance. You will have to keep the position on BattleTurn class, you can add other attributes to it.

Comment: Oh, if you don't mind, could you please explain what will this class do? F.ex user presses the cell, then it sees, whether there's a ship or not and write to List the following parameters: Rectangular of hit and boolean (hit / not hit). And in onDraw() method I call this list to paint all dots and yellow rectangulars again?

Comment: Well, the battle turn is just to save each turn so you can save the state for all turns. Changed a bit the answer...